# Finding Palindrome and its Binary

Tags: java

i try to find palindrome and its binary,right now i getting palindrome number correctly but its binary not print correctly kindly help me what mistake i have done.

```
     package Palindrome
     public class PalindromeNnumber {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     for (int i = 11; i < 100; i++) {
     isPalindrome(i);
       }
     }
     private static void isPalindrome(int i) {
     int reverse = 0;
     int input = i;
     while (i > 0) {
     int remainder = i % 10;
     reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
     i = i / 10;
     }
     int rnumber = reverse;
     if (input == reverse) {
     System.out.println("Palindrome Number " + reverse);
     isBinary(rnumber);
     }
    }

   private static void isBinary(int rnumber) {
    int reversebinary = 0;

    //Finding Binary Number for the input number

    while (rnumber > 0) {

   int remainderb = rnumber % 2;

   reversebinary = reversebinary * 10 + remainderb;

   rnumber = rnumber / 10;
   }
  System.out.println("Binary Numbers are :"+reversebinary);
  }
 }
```

My Output:

```
Palindrome Number 11
Binary Numbers are :1101
Palindrome Number 22
Binary Numbers are :1101
Palindrome Number 33
Binary Numbers are :100001
Palindrome Number 44
Binary Numbers are :1101
Palindrome Number 55
Binary Numbers are :111011
Palindrome Number 66
Binary Numbers are :100001
Palindrome Number 77
Binary Numbers are :1011001
Palindrome Number 88
Binary Numbers are :1101
Palindrome Number 99
Binary Numbers are :1100011
```

Comment: [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)

Comment: @MikeSamuel while i am using Integer.toBinaryString(int i) it print exact Binary value but i try to print using while loop it print correctly 0-15 after that it won't print exact binary value what's problem in my code

Comment: Can you provide an example of a value `Integer.toBinaryString` isn't correct for?  `Integer.toBinaryString(16).equals("10000")` on my system which seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(int i)
```

Comment: while i am using Integer.toBinaryString(int i) it print exact Binary value but i try to print using while loop it print correctly 0-15 after that it won't print exact binary value what's problem in my code..